# Querying iframes tagged as "Ad"

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors

When I look at the source of some pages I saw a tag as "This frame was identified as an ad frame".
Is there a way query to these iframes? How can I query like that iframe on the DOM Tree? Or How can I detect Ad Frames? You can see what I meant in the picture below, It is red-circled on the picture.

PS: I used Chrome, to be able to see the Advertisements I disabled AdBlocker and I used Incognito mode.

[image]

Comment: Please share more details - how **exactly** does such tagging work? I don't think that this is a core feature of all browsers

Comment: Does your browser have any ad blocking extensions installed?

Comment: @j08691 I used the latest version of Chrome and an Adblocker installed but I opened the page in the Incognito window, which the adblocker is not active on it.

Comment: I think it's done by this part of the chromium source code https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/ad_tagging.md

Comment: From what I can understand from the above document, it looks like it's a filtering based on whether the src matches [a file like this](https://github.com/chromium/chromium-ads-detection/blob/master/third_party/filter_lists/9.10.1/filter_list) but I fail to understand the file format

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR:
DevTools checks if

- iframe is at the end of DOM tree (or at least it should be)
- is injected by ad script
- is from another domain than viewed page (most important)

Then it classifies it as an "ad" iframe and then attach `ad` indicator the the DOM element.

---

If you are interested:

Chromium browsers (like Chrome and Edge) **can detect which `<iframe>` element in DOM is an advertisement frame**.

It is detected by DevTools internal SDK.

As you see those iframes have `ad` indicator added by DevTools.

Notice that those iframes are injected into the page AFTER `</body>` closing tag  and before closing `</html>` tag. This is standard for **injecting ad-frames, they are supposed to be the last elements in the DOM tree**.

[image]

There are several indicators (called **Adorners**) in DevTools.
The most common adorners you propably noticed in DOM tree are `flex` for CSS [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) containers and `grid` for CSS [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) containers.

If you are interested, those indicators are defined in DevTools AdornerManager:

[image]
*devtools-frontend\front_end\panels\elements\components\AdornerManager.ts*

As you can see one of those adorners is an "ad"

DevTools uses following code to add ad adorner for an iframe which is serving ad purpose:

[image: ElementsTreeElement.ts]
*devtools-frontend\front_end\panels\elements\ElementsTreeElement.ts*

As you see there is simple check
`if (node.isAdFrameNode())`

`isAdFrameNode()` is a method of DOMNode class:

[image]
*devtools-frontend\front_end\core\sdk\DOMModel.ts*

Most important part of that code is:

`return frame.adFrameType() !== Protocol.Page.AdFrameType.None;`

which returns if checked iframe "adFrameType" is not an AdFrameType equal of "none"

[image]
*D:\www\devtools\devtools-frontend\front_end\generated\protocol.ts*

As you can notice there is also enum of AdFrameExplanation which can be:

- ParentIsAd = 'ParentIsAd',
- CreatedByAdScript = 'CreatedByAdScript',
- MatchedBlockingRule = 'MatchedBlockingRule',

If that check will classify iframe as an ad, it ads this small little ticker at the end of the  element in DevTools:

[image]

You can look up the DevTools code here:

https://chromium.googlesource.com/devtools/devtools-frontend/+/6add435a1f13883930defd41ddc020788faea832/front_end/panels/elements/ElementsTreeElement.ts

https://chromium.googlesource.com/devtools/devtools-frontend/+/6add435a1f13883930defd41ddc020788faea832/front_end/core/sdk/DOMModel.ts

https://chromium.googlesource.com/devtools/devtools-frontend/+/6add435a1f13883930defd41ddc020788faea832/front_end/core/sdk/FrameManager.ts